# Optimal value of decision variable leads to inconsistency

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

$\epsilon$ is a random variable with support in $(0.8,0.95)$ and pdf $f(\epsilon)$. The following equation arises out of a business problem:
$ENP=800*A*E(\epsilon)+ 9000 - 250*\int_{0.8}^{\frac{0.75}{A}}(0.75-A\epsilon)f(\epsilon)d\epsilon- 600*\int_{\frac{0.75}{A}}^{0.95}(A\epsilon-0.75)f(\epsilon)d\epsilon$
On substituting the distribution of $\epsilon$ and simplifying we get, $ENP=700*A+ 9000 - \frac{250}{0.3}*(\frac{0.75^2}{A}+A*0.8^{2}-1.2)-\frac{600}{0.3}*(\frac{0.75^2}{A}+A*0.95^{2}-1.425)$. Here $A$ is a decision variable. On optimizing above equation w.r.t. $A$ we get optimal value $A^{*}=0.9863$ and $\frac{0.75}{A^{*}}=0.76$.Why is this happening?$\frac{0.75}{A^{*}}$ should lie in the range of integration i.e. $(0.8,0.95)$.

Comment: How are you performing the optimization? Are you using a program, optimizing it by hand, etc.?

Comment: I am doing analytical optimization by hand. Usual first derivative and second derivative rule.

Comment: checking for sign of second derivative and using first order condition.

Comment: Since the variable wrt optimization also influences the integration border, you must use Leibniz integral rule: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule - there should be some $-0.75/A^2$ term. Also, are you sure that your problem is globally concave?

Comment: Yes on using leibnitz rule, the first derivative comes as $(700+\frac{850}{0.3}*\frac{0.75^2}{A^2}-\frac{250}{0.3}*0.8^2-\frac{600}{0.3}*0.95^2)$

Comment: The second derivative is $\frac{-850}{0.3}*0.75^2*\frac{2}{A^3}$. So the function is concave for all $A\in (0,\inf)$

Comment: Can anyone please help me find the anomaly here?